# want to zip folder and want unzip without parent directory not happend in ubunto

Tags: command-line, zip

i have folder and file like this

x (folder)

x has 2 files

a.py and y.py

now i am creating a zip with this command

```
cd /home/x/

ls
```

a.py and y.py

```
sudo zip -r ./zi.zip .
```

it create a zip

zi.zip

when i extract this then it give a folder "zi" and in this folder "a.py" and "y.py"

but i don't want zi folder

i want where ever i extract this folder it give me a.py and y.py not a folder

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are extracting the archive using a graphical tool, as `file-roller`.

Using the terminal for both compressing and extracting, you get the following:

```
ls
a.py  y.py

zip -r ./zi.zip .
  adding: y.py (stored 0%)
  adding: a.py (stored 0%)

unzip zi.zip 
Archive:  zi.zip
replace y.py? [y]es, [n]o, [A]ll, [N]one, [r]ename: y
 extracting: y.py                    
replace a.py? [y]es, [n]o, [A]ll, [N]one, [r]ename: y
 extracting: a.py

ls
a.py  y.py  zi.zip
```

so the files are extracted to the same directory where you are.

The simplest solution would be to open the archive using `file-roller` and, after clicking on "Extract", deselecting the "Keep directory structure" flag. In this way the files are extracted in the current folder.

Note: this causes to lose all the structure of the archive, so if there were multiple directories, they will be lost.

Hope it helps.

Comment: zip -r ./zi.zip . I am using this but i cannot use this unzip command because i am creating lambda aws they unzip folder do you have any other software to do this?